# Where is the "See Through" selecting button in 2.81?

Tags: selection-tools

In blender 2.81,Layout workspace, Edit mode, Face select,using Box-selecting tool, I try to select all the faces of a cube at once, but only the front faces are selected.
Blender 2.79 had a "See Through" button next to the Vertex,Edge,Face buttons allowing to select all at once .
Is there such an option in 2.81? I could not find it.

Comment: Mark the answer as solved please.

Answer (score 3):

It's still there.
Right next to viewport shading options.

Now it's called X-Ray.
Works in Edit and Object mode.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for this very fast and very useful answer

Comment: Glad to be of help :). You can now mark the question as solved, for other lost souls coming from Blender 2.79.

Comment: @aguarneri Please don't just add thank you as a comment, upvote the answer instead. If you feel it completely solved your problem consider marking it accepted